# Entrance several rows in List

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have simple class:

```
public class ForStream {
   private int shortId;
   private long longId;

public ForStream(int shortId, long longId) {
    this.shortId = shortId;
    this.longId = longId;
}

public int getShortId() {
    return shortId;
}

public void setShortId(int shortId) {
    this.shortId = shortId;
}

public long getLongId() {
    return longId;
}

public void setLongId(long longId) {
    this.longId = longId;
}
}
```

It is necessary to find the occurrence of several substrings in an array. I do this (maybe it's ineffective):

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<ForStream> resList = List.of(
            new ForStream(689, 10000000001L),
            new ForStream(781, 10000000001L),
            new ForStream(785, 10000000001L),
            new ForStream(689, 10000000002L),
            new ForStream(689, 10000000003L),
            new ForStream(781, 10000000004L),
            new ForStream(785, 10000000004L)
    );

    boolean isEqual = !resList.stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getLongId() == 10000000001L)
            .filter(p -> p.getShortId() == 689)
            .filter(p -> p.getShortId() == 781)
            .filter(p -> p.getShortId() == 785)
            .collect(Collectors.toList()).isEmpty();

}
```

It's return false. But 689, 781 and 785 contains to list.

Comment: `.filter(p -> p.getShortId() == 689).filter(p -> p.getShortId() == 781)`: that can only return an empty stream. A shortId can't be equal to 689 and 781 a the same time. I have no idea of what this code is supposed to do. You're vaguely talking about subsstrings and an array, but there are no strings in this code, and no array either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work. You are filtering out on single elements. But what you wish to do is compare it with a list of values. What you are doing is a `&&` but what you require is `||`

```
   boolean isEqual = !resList.stream()
                .filter(p -> p.getLongId() == 10000000001L)
                .filter(p -> Arrays.asList(689, 781, 785).contains(p.getShortId()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()).isEmpty();
```

Comment: But instead of collecting all matching elements into a `List`, just to check whether it is not empty, you should use an operation like `anyMatch`, e.g. `boolean isEqual = resList.stream()  .anyMatch(p -> p.getLongId() == 10000000001L && Arrays.asList(689, 781, 785).contains(p.getShortId()));`